# Iterating vector of unique pointer

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, c++14, unique-ptr

I read all the possible references about smart pointers, move semantics and iterators, but I'm still struggling to understand why the following C++14 code segfaults:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  vector<unique_ptr<int>> ints (10);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    unique_ptr<int> number = make_unique<int>(5);
    ints.push_back(move(number));
  }

  for(auto& n : ints) {
    cout << *n << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ <filename> -std=c++14 -o <executable>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vector<unique_ptr<int>> ints (10);
```

This initializes a `vector` of 10 `unique_ptr`s with default values. That is, null pointers.

You then attempt to dereference them in a loop.

You probably intended to say

```
vector<unique_ptr<int>> ints;
ints.reserve(10); // changes capacity, but not size
```

Comment: Or `vector<unique_ptr<int>> ints(10,5)` without the loop

Comment: That won't work, @Trevir. `5` would be used to initialize `unique_ptr<int>` which is nonsensical.

Comment: @Trevir but you can't copy a `unique_ptr`, which is required of the default value if you provide one.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<unique_ptr<int>> ints (10);

// ...

ints.push_back(move(number));
```

You're allocating a vector with 10, default-constructed elements, then you add elements with `push_back`: the first 10 elements are initialized with null pointers, thus the segfault.

Try:

```
vector<unique_ptr<int>> ints (10);

for(auto& ptr : ints) {
    ptr = make_unique<int>(5);
}
```